# Apache .htaccess variable for root directory?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

On my localhost and live website I have different .htaccess directives like this one:

```
AuthUserFile /path/to/folder/.htpasswd
```

Is there a way to dynamically indicate the root directory in the .htaccess file so that I don't need to have different .htaccess files for local vs live hosts?

Comment: Do you mean `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_authn_file.html#authuserfile :

> File-path is the path to the user file. If it is not absolute, it is
>   treated as relative to the ServerRoot.

So one of the solution is to use a relative path. You should use something like `../auth/.htpasswd` with the auth directory outside of your web root (so here for example if the .htaccess is on your web root).

PS: %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} is only a mod_rewrite variable AFAIK, so you do not have it for AuthUserFile instruction

Comment: I'd like to note; in my experience, if you have a sub-domain setup within your main domain path `domain\subdomain` and each have their own htaccess files. The htaccess in the sub-domain folder will take over the main htaccess file when accessing the subdomain via its folder path `http://example.com/subdomainfolderpath/emptyfolder/` however will look for its associated files in the webroot of the main domain. - This trick here `../adirectoryinsubdomaindir/afile.html` works extremely well in making each subdomain htaccess file work as intended regardless of the way in which it is accessed.